# Brezis' Functional Analysis Exercise 2.5

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

The exercise is from Brezis's functional analysis page 50:

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $\varepsilon_n$ be a sequence of positive
>   numbers such that $\lim \varepsilon_n = 0$. Further, let $(f_n)$ be a sequence
>   in $E^{\star}$ statisfying the property,
>   $$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
>      \exists r > 0, \forall x \in E \, \text{with}\, \| x \| < r, \exists C
>      (x) \in \mathbb{R} \quad \text{such that}\\
>      \\
>      \langle f_n, x \rangle \leqslant \varepsilon_n \| f_n \| + C (x) \quad
>      \forall n.
>    \end{array} \right. $$
>   Prove that $(f_n)$ is bounded. (**Hint**: Introduce $g_n = f_n / (1 +
> \varepsilon_n \| f_n \|)$.)

Here is my solution:

> Fix $x \neq 0$, we have
>   $$ g_n (x) = \frac{f_n (x)}{1 + \varepsilon_n \| f_n \|} = \frac{2 \| x \|
>    }{r}  \frac{f_n \left( \frac{r}{2 \| x \|} x \right)}{1 + \varepsilon_n \|
>    f_n \|} \leqslant \frac{2 \| x \| }{r}  \frac{C \left( \frac{r}{2 \| x \|}
>    x \right) + \varepsilon_n \| f_n \|}{1 + \varepsilon_n \| f_n \|} $$ $$ = \frac{2
>    \| x \| }{r} \left( \frac{C (x) - 1}{1 + \varepsilon_n \| f_n \|} + 1
>    \right) \leqslant \frac{2 \| x \|}{r}  (| C (x) - 1 | + 1) . $$
>   for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $\sup_n g_n (x)$ is finite for all $x \in
> E$.
>
> By uniform bounded principle, we derive that
>   $$ g_n (x) \leqslant M \| x \| $$
>   for all $x \in E$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So we get
>   $$ f_n (x) \leqslant M (1 + \varepsilon_n \| f_n \|)  \| x \| . $$
>   If we restrict $\| x \| \leqslant 1$, and taking the supremum with respect to
>   $x$, we have
>   $$ \| f_n \| \leqslant M + \varepsilon_n M \| f_n \| . $$
>   Since $0 < \varepsilon_n \rightarrow 0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$
>   such that $\varepsilon_n M < 1 / 2$ when $n \geqslant n_0 + 1$. In other
>   words,
>   $$ \| f_n \| \leqslant 2 M $$
>   when $n \geqslant n_0 + 1$.
>
> Taking $N = \max \{ \| f_1 \|, \cdots, \| f_{n_0}
> \|, 2 M \}$, we have $\| f_n \| \leqslant N$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>   Therefore, $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $E^{\star}$.

**Question**: I am not quite confident with my proof, because it seems a little bit unclean for me. I would be glad for anyone to check my proof or to give a neat proof. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.